# Center Form Dynamically Add Elements Remain Center?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a basic HTML form that I am centering.  I am using jQuery plugin to dynamically validate that the fields are required.  When it adds the "Field is required" message after the text box, it causes the form/table to shift due to the fact that it is in a table.  This makes sense.

The question I have is what is the best way to keep the table/form centered on the page as but allow any dynamically added elements that are added "after" the text boxes to not shift the form?  See my example here: http://jsbin.com/amasa4/3/

I don't necessarily need it to remain a table if it is easier done without while keeping the same style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did to solve this was set the label class of the errors that are dynamically added to absolute.  That way I could still center the form using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I use right now is to center your table with javascript instead of css (`margin: 0 auto;`). I have my form in some kind of modal dialog.
So the function for my case looks like:

```
$.fn.center = function() {

    this.css("position", "absolute");

    this.css("left", "50%");

    this.css("margin-left", -((this.width()) / 2) + "px");

    return this;

}
```

And yeah, if you have multiple steps in your form, you will have to center your table every time you go to the next or previous step.

Here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/amasa4/4/)

**EDIT**: I created the following [hack](http://jsbin.com/amasa4/6/edit), looks really ugly, but if you are desperate and there is no other solution you can use it =) What I did there is added a dummy div before the form and resized it with javascript based on form's width. You can use 1 table instead of 2 divs and then resize the first dummy column instead. Also note that you will need to resize the whole thing again on window resize event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That gets me half way there.  Now the problem I am having is any divs below the table in the document lose their flow.  See here: http://jsbin.com/amasa4/5/edit  I can't really introduce extra div wraps because the footer is in a master page while the table is in an index page.  Is this all possible without JS?

Comment: I've updated my answer, don't really see any better solution for now.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Ended up going with a much simpler solution still using CSS to center the form!

Comment: No worries, I actually came here to suggest that absolute error label solution =)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
 label{
    display:block;
  }
  td{
    vertical-align:top;
  }
```